# Will 6-gauge THWN work in my 60-foot run?

Tags: gauge

I will be installing a 48-amp Emporia car charger outside.  It will be connected to a 60-amp breaker.  Half of the 60-foot ​wire run will be along the edge of the ceiling in my basement, and the other half will be in an 18-inch trench in my yard.  Assuming my main panel can safely handle an  additional 60-amp breaker with a 48-amp continuous load, can I safely use 6-gauge THWN in PVC conduit for the entire run, without issues of overheating or problematic voltage drops?

Comment: 6 AWG is fine. Copper or aluminum, though aluminum would depend on the EVSE being able to use it (Tesla can't, but I have no idea about the Emporia). But you need to a **load calculation**. You have to do a load calculation based on service, main panel (if it is breakered lower than the full service) and any relevant subpanels (e.g., if you have service -> main panel -> subpanel -> EVSE). If that says 60A, great. If it says 0A you're already in trouble. If it says something in between (e.g., 30A or 40A) go with that value and *not any more than that*.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 3):

### Trenching

The trench needs to have 18" of cover - top of pipe is 18" not bottom.  All conduit must be assembled, complete, before any wire is pulled in - you *do not* sleeve sticks of conduit over the wires as you go. For several reasons.  All conduit must be built "possible to pull", so no plumbing elbows LOL, and all pulling points (such as LB elbows) need to remain accessible forever (so not buried, mudded over or faced into a wall).  No more than 360 degrees bend between pulling points (but if you're the puller, *try* to keep it to 90, or 180 at the absolute outside. That way you won't need the electrician for the truck full of specialty pulling tools!)

### Load Calculation (and charge rate sanity)

Your NEC Article 220 Load Calculation needs to support the EV charge rate - this is not a thing you should be "arm-waving" or theorycrafting about.  Talk to your AHJ when you pull the permit for this.  But there are 2 secrets here: #1 just because the EVSE ("charger" [but not!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMxB7zA-e4Y)) is capable of 60A doesn't mean you're obliged to the cost of a 60A circuit and the service upgrade necessary to add 60A to most panels.  [SAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAE_International) knew "service upgrades" would be a sales killer, so they embedded the tech to make this easy.  **EVs can be hard-configured to any circuit ampacity** you please (or have capacity for). Tesla doesn't make a 15A, 20A, 30A, 40A and 50A version of the Wall Connector, for instance. You flip a switch.

And even further, 60A is [gross overkill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w&t=1695s) for just about everyone but Uber drivers.  You don't need to charge the whole battery everyday, just the amount you used (and even then it's not the end of the world if you're not at 100% after an extraordinary day the day before).  A simple 20A (240V) circuit will replace 100-200 miles a night depending on the car and the night. You can't really go by city gas mileage, because gas cars are very wasteful when stopped/in traffic but EVs are very efficient. (That's also how the Prius got such phenomenal city MPG).

#8 THHN gets you 50A, #10 gets 30A and #12 gets 20A.

But we'll loop back to this.

### Voltage drop

Below about 150' I wouldn't worry about voltage drop.  Well I suppose you could just for financial reasons: go ahead and "run the numbers" [in a voltage drop calc](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-vdrop) with 48A as amps and it'll tell you what % of your power/money you'll lose to voltage drop.  You can try different cable sizes and see the effect on voltage drop.  Make sure to make sensible assumptions: you won't be filling the car to 0% to 100% every night, as discussed, so don't say 80kWH x 365 days! A good rule of thumb is 3 miles per kWH, so if you drive 12,000 miles a year, call it 4,000 kWH/year.  If you're paying 15 cents a kWH that's $600/year - saving *1% of that* isn't worth the cost of bigger wire.

And one option is to go ahead and run the #6 and then down-clock the EVSE to a more prudent ampacity. That will cut voltage drop in proportion.

### I really want that 60A, though

First, consider aluminum wire for the long haul - far cheaper but will require costly Polaris couplers to step down to copper wire for attachment to the EVSE.  The breakers are all good for aluminum. EVSE makers fail to use AL-ready terminals for some reason.  #6 aluminum gets you 50A and #4 gets you 65A.

Second, even if your Load Calculation does not support 60A of additional load (that's how it's calculated for 48A actual),  we can cheat. Certain EVSEs ([not the Emporia, unfortunately](https://www.reddit.com/r/evcharging/comments/11jphw1/comment/jci3ecl/)) can install Current Transformers (CTs) on your main service wires and simply tweak charge rate "on the fly" to avoid overload. In today's US market you'd most likely be in a Wallbox Pulsar Plus, with hardwired signal cables between (so that conduit better be pullable lol).  In Europe you'd probably use a Myenergi ZAPPI which uses radio to talk to the CT module.

If you will be charging two or more EVs, 60A is perfectly sensible for sharing. Thanks to more EVSE magic, multiple EVSEs can dynamically power-share, splitting the 60A among only the cars that are actively charging. Since most cars don't need that much, this can support a surprising number of cars! Back when we had an outbound sales/service business in a major snow-belt metro, we could've run all 3 cars with 30A.

Last note, there's news: Tesla open-sourced their plug and the industry is switching to it faster than I've ever seen the auto industry move. This car will be J1772/"Fetch"*  connector, but your next one will probably be NACS/Tesla.

* It really needs a better name than J1772. I'm calling it "Fetch" in the hopes that'll take off.

Comment: Polaris Gray 6 to 14 AWG connectors are approved for 6 AWG, but is that just for copper? These are a fraction of the cost of the larger Polaris connectors.  Are Polaris Gray approved for #6 aluminum?

Comment: TLDR still+1....

Comment: "Fetch"? No. "Bob". As in Microsoft Bob - as in a product that didn't last long. Though J1772 isn't *that* bad.

Comment: @JimStewart -- the regular Polaris connectors should be available in a #4-#14 size

Comment: Thanks for your detailled answer, Harper - Reinstate Monica!